# unshift method keep pushing new objects in picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, picker

So i have a picker in React Native which the item is based on api, and the api contain array of objects like this

`[{"code": "N", "description": "Normal", "id": 1, "note": null, "tolerance": 600}, {"code": "V", "description": "Variable", "id": 2, "note": null, "tolerance": null}, {"code": "F", "description": "Flexible", "id": 3, "note": null, "tolerance": null}]`

and i want to add some kind of placeholder for the picker so i used the unshift method but when I clicked an item in the picker the unshift keeps pushing new item inside the array

```js
render(){
let scheduleTypes = this.props.schedules;
    scheduleTypes.unshift({"description":"Schedule Type", "id": "0"});
  return(
    <PickerWrapper items={scheduleTypes} onSelect={(item) => this.setState({ type_absen: item })}/>
  )
}
```

my question is how is this keep pushing and how to stop it?

Comment: First thing that strikes me is that you are mutating this.props.schedules array. You should have below code in place of what you have now: `let scheduleTypes = [...this.props.schedules]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're `unshift`-ing in your `render` method, and changing the `schedules` prop. What you should be doing if you want to add only that particular item to your list is this:

```
render(){
let scheduleTypes = this.props.schedules;
  return(
    <PickerWrapper items={[{"description":"Schedule Type", "id": "0"}, ...scheduleTypes]} onSelect={(item) => this.setState({ type_absen: item })}/>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
render(){
let scheduleTypes = this.props.schedules;
scheduleTypes.unshift({"description":"Schedule Type", "id": "0"}); // <= this needs to be removed from render
  return(
    <PickerWrapper items={scheduleTypes} onSelect={(item) => this.setState({ type_absen: item })}/>
  )
}
```

So, let me explain your code:

1. You add an item to your array. OK!
2. You re-render your component when select an item. OK!
3. Your component call render again, and poof, you have addition item in your array.

I'll make it shortly, this is how a React Native (RN) Component runs respectively:

1. construct(): this will construct your component at first.
2. componentWillMount(): you can put some codes in here that will be handled before your component shows up (render).
3. render(): everything you want to show in that component.
4. componentDidMount(): do something after showing up.

When you call `setState()`, it will re-run your `render()` function. Since you put your `unshift()` in your `render()`, it will run `unshift()` one more time. And that's the problem.

To fix this, you can put your `unshift()` in `componentWillMount()` or `construct()`. For more detail, please read and investigate React Native Lifecycle first. [ReactJS State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) (this link is from ReactJS's document, but it's mostly the same)